# Why are my bootstrap carousel next/prev buttons not working for my WP theme?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

While this same carousel works in another WP theme I created, when I switched it, along with all the images and ID tags, it no longer changes images. Another peculiar thing is that after I refresh the page (running on local host via Xamp) the url includes the carousel ID tag after the theme name (localhost/seahorse/#SeahorseCarousel) -- which is odd, and I'm not sure why.

The bootstrap cdns are working as all other bootstrap elements work fine.
I've used the same image on all three slides and copied and pasted the file dir to be sure there are no mistakes.

The image appears on the first slide, but then doesn't change to any other.
When inspected, there are no errors.

Thanks for any help!

The carousel:

```
    <div id="SeahorseCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#SeahorseCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#SeahorseCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#SeahorseCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" srcset="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/skyline.jpg,
                <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/skyline.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 500px) 50vw, 100vw" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/skyline.jpg" alt="web-banner"></img>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption text-left aboutTag">
                        <h3>"We will be using JD3D for our next development and would have no hesitation in recommending their services" - Jon Morgan, Griffon Developments</h3>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btnCarousel" href="" role="button">About Us &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/skyline.jpg"></img>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h1>We Offer Affordable Tiered Packages<br>
                            For Different Needs & Budgets</h1>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btnCarousel" href="" role="button">Our Services &raquo;</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" srcset="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/skyline.jpg,
                <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/skyline.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 500px) 50vw, 100vw" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/skyline.jpg" alt="web-banner"></img>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="carousel-caption text-left aboutTag">
                        <h3>"We will be using JD3D for our next development and would have no hesitation in recommending their services" - Jon Morgan, Griffon Developments</h3>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btnCarousel" href="" role="button">About Us &raquo;</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#SeahorseCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#SeahorseCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

The css:

```
#SeahorseCarousel {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

}

#SeahorseCarousel h3 {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: var(--dark-grey);
  padding: 1rem;

}

.carousel-inner {
  width: 100%;
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 100vh;
}

.carousel-caption {
  bottom: 3rem;
  padding: 0 10px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-item>img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Scripts

```
function Seahorse_register_styles (){

    $version = wp_get_theme() -> get ('Version');
    wp_enqueue_style('gfontOpenSans', "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap", array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('gfontArchivo', "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap", array(), '1.0', 'all');
       wp_enqueue_style('Seahorse-bootstrap', "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", array(), '1.0', 'all');
    // wp_enqueue_style('Seahorse-scss', get_template_directory_uri(). "style.min.css", array(), 1.0,'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('Seahorse-css', get_template_directory_uri(). "/style.css", array(), 'Version', 'all');
   wp_enqueue_style('seahorse-cloudflare', "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css", array(), '1.0', 'all');
   wp_enqueue_style('ftawesome', "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/css/all.css", array(), '1.0', 'all');
   wp_enqueue_style('aos', "https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css", array(), '1.0', 'all');
   wp_enqueue_style('shake', "https://csshake.surge.sh/csshake.min.css", array(), '1.0', 'all');
   
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Seahorse_register_styles');



function Seahorse_register_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script('bootscripts', "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js", array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootscripts2', "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js", array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootscripts3', "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js", array(), '1.0', 'all');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'Seahorse_register_scripts');
```

Comment: Working fine for me. What error did you get? did you check in the console? working fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/j3vobnry/1/

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. Good to see the code works. I don't get an error, which is why I'm having a trouble, console is clean. It's just not changing. It must be something with how I have the wp theme set up as I don't know why carousel id is being added into the url.  Still in the early stages of learning to create themes.